# Согласно документ(ам/ов)?

Tags: управление

Как правильно:
"Согласно руководящих документов"  или
"Согласно руководящим документам"?

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно: "Согласно руководящих документов" или "Согласно
> руководящим документам"?

В настоящее время правилен только второй вариант: ***согласно руководящим документам.***

[***Из словаря Розенталя:***](http://upravlenie.academic.ru/2220)

> **согласно**
>
> ***чему*** (устар. ***чего***) и ***с чем***.
>
> 1. ***чему*** (на основании *чего-л.*). *Согласно предписанию. Согласно уставу. Жениховой родне, согласно уговору, поднесли по три
>    рюмки водки* (Шолохов). *Писать одного или будут еще кандидаты,
>    согласно ваших слов?* (Вишневский).
> 2. ***с чем*** (в соответствии с *чем-л.*). *Согласно с требованиями морали. [Она] нередко изменяет свои распоряжения согласно с его
>    советам* (Салтыков-Щедрин).
>
> ***Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь.***

Интересно другое. Розенталь считал допустимыми два варианта: ***согласно чему*** и ***согласно с чем***. Другие же лингвисты вариант ***согласно с чем*** либо вообще не упоминают,  либо говорят о его *устаревании*.

Из книги Льва Ивановича Скворцова ***"Культура русской речи: словарь-справочник"***:

> В официально-деловой, канцелярской речи довольно часто встречаются
> конструкции *согласно* с родительным падежом зависимых слов: *согласно
> чего*. Например: *согласно приказа, согласно заявления* и т.п.  В
> письменной деловой речи предлог *согласно* употреблялся с ХVIII века в
> трех различных конструкциях: *согласно чего, согласно чему* и
> *согласно с чем.*
>
> Общелитературный язык усвоил только сочетание предлога с дательным
> падежом: ***согласно чему.***

А вот что про ***согласно с чем*** говорится в этом словаре:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> **Устаревающим** вариантом становится конструкция ***согласно с чем***: *В
> дальнейшем они действовали согласно с решением администрации.*

Comment: Розенталь вообще был изрядным консерватором))). На самом деле тут другое. Новая норма почему-то воспринимается многими как пример грамматического творчества большевиков (что неверно), а старая, канцелярская чуть ли ни как пример вольнодумия. Видимо, Розенталь просто решил примерить либералов с консерваторами, хотя на тот момент это было уже не актуально.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же, "Согласно руководящим документ**ам**".

Одна из возможных гипотез распространения ошибочного варианта падежа в подобных выражениях: в первоначальном выражении "согласно пункт**у** 4 (реально, п.4) документа" кто-то упростил его простым отбрасыванием упоминания о пункте (за ненадобностью, как это часто бывает, информации о номере), оставив неисправленным падеж. Вот и вышло "согласно документа", передававшееся по цепочке служебных инстанций.

Comment: Согласно руководящих документов - старая норма.

Comment: Да, @Alex_ander, гипотеза эта несколько опрометчива. ))) "Согласно чего" - это более древний вариант, ныне считающийся просторечным. Так что обсуждать нужно скорее гипотезы как это "согласно чему" стало нормой - и/или почему старая норма сейчас все ещё так популярна.

Answer (score 0):

> согласно
>   чему (устар. чего) и с чем.
>   1. чему (на основании чего-л.). Согласно предписанию. Согласно уставу. Жениховой родне, согласно уговору, поднесли по три рюмки водки (Шолохов). Писать одного или будут еще кандидаты, согласно ваших слов? (Вишневский).

https://upravlenie.academic.ru/2220

Ещё раз прочитайте, что написал Розенталь и какой пример он привёл: "**согласно** ваших **слов**". Вывод сами сделаете. (да, да, я видел "устар", дело не в нём)