# Актуальность справочников Розенталя

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите, пожалуйста, обосновать, что справочникам Розенталя можно доверять, учитывая годы жизни автора. Спасибо большое заранее.

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под " учитывая годы жизни автора"?

Comment: Я о том, что Д.Э. Розенталь умер почти 25 лет назад, для языка, насколько я знаю, это достаточно много. Буду благодарна за разъяснения, если я ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Розенталь (1900 - 1994), условно говоря, это "наше всё".

[Розенталь, Дитмар Эльяшевич | ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C,_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

Профессор, заведующий кафедрой стилистики русского языка факультета журналистики МГУ в 1962—1986. Долгое время руководил факультетской группой дикторов телевидения и радио СССР.

Розенталь не был академическим специалистом по лингвистике русского языка, степень кандидата педагогических наук была присуждена ему за учебник итальянского языка ([ссылка](http://www.intelros.ru/readroom/nz/nz_71/6973-istoriya-s-orfografiej-neudavshiesyareformy-russkogo-pravopisaniya-vtoroj-poloviny-xx-veka.html)). **Тем не менее, он считается родоначальником практической стилистики, одним из основных разработчиков и истолкователей правил современного русского правописания.** Автор более 150 учебников (публиковались с 1925 года), пособий, справочников, словарей, популярных книг, а также исследовательских работ по русскому языку, культуре речи, стилистике, правописанию, лингводидактике.

Обоснование

1) В основе всех разработок Розенталя лежат "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" 1956 года, которые никто не отменял. **Это официальный свод правил**, утвержденный на государственном уровне.

2) Все последующие реформы правописания **официально  приняты не были**, в том числе последняя реформа 2000 года.

В конце концов в 2006 году был опубликован справочник «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под редакцией Владимира Лопатина, который был предложен специалистам для обсуждения, **уже без «радикальных» перемен.** Таким образом, вопрос изменений в современном правописании еще не закрыт. В 2005 году вышло новое, исправленное и дополненное, издание «**Русского орфографического словаря»** объемом около 180 тысяч слов. Этот нормативный словарь утвержден Академией наук, в отличие от «Правил», которые должны утверждаться правительством России, и уже является **обязательным.**

3) **Таким образом, мы имеем возможность пользоваться обоими источниками.** Между ним нет принципиальных противоречий, но свод  Розенталя отличается более подробным изложением и объяснением правил, им удобно пользоваться, и ссылки на этот свод вполне правомерны. В Правила Лопатина (ПАС) внесены некоторые изменения, изложение более краткое, этот свод также можно использовать, в том числе для сравнения и выявление возможных различий.

4) **Конечно, язык развивается, появляются новые слова, осваиваются новые грамматические формы, и это должно отражаться в правилах**. Проблема реформы правописания продолжает обсуждаться, но общий характер подхода к реформированию меняется. Появляются следующие идеи: смягчение «орфографического режима», допущение некоторых вариативных написаний, своеобразное орфографическое «самоупорядочивание (в связи с развитием Интернета) и т.д.

[История с орфографией. Неудавшиеся реформы русского правописания второй половины ХХ века | intelros.ru](http://www.intelros.ru/readroom/nz/nz_71/6973-istoriya-s-orfografiej-neudavshiesyareformy-russkogo-pravopisaniya-vtoroj-poloviny-xx-veka.html)

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за ответ и ссылку!

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Интереснейший материал.

Answer (score 5):

Интересно бы знать, а чем руководствуются противники признания актуальности справочников?!

Вообще постановка вопроса мне кажется слишком поверхностной.
У Розенталя, наверное, десяток, фундаментальных именно справочников по наиболее важным темам (стилистика, орфография, пунктуация) - не считая более узконаправленных. Актуальность разных разделов меняется с разной скоростью. Поэтому стоит говорить всё-таки конкретно.

1. Стилистика. У Розенталя есть фундаментальная "Практическая стилистика русского языка"
   https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/SLAVSTUD151/Prakticheskaya_stilistika_Rozental_D_E.pdf
   и "Правописание и стилистика".

Представления о стилистике всегда базируются во многом на субъкетивном авторитетном мнении известных авторов. Поскольку никого более авторитетного пока не появилось, а объективно опровергнуть Розенталя невозможно в силу самой специфики подхода, то Розенталь был и остается самым авторитетным автором в этом вопросе. Я специально не отслеживал, но, судя по всему, фундаментальных, претендующих на звание нормативного источника, трудов по стилистике после Розенталя не появилось. Все авторы в лучшем случае дополняют Розенталя, признавая актуальность его работ. Думаю, это само по себе убедительный довод. Разумеется, это не значит, что какие-то отдельные положения Розенталя не могли устареть.

2. Орфография. Ну возьмите первую часть самого известного справочника.
   *"Справочник по русскому языку - орфография и пунктуация." (Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.)* 
   Орфография принципиально не менялась с 1956 г. Небольшие орфографические уточнения в книги, изданные при жизни Розенталя, естественно, не могли попасть, но, кажется, даже их учитывали при посмертных изданиях.
3. Пунктуация. Вторая часть того же справочника. Здесь, согласен, надо относиться с некоторой осторожностью, пунктуация такая вещь, что может зависеть от авторского понимания текста, а границы позволенного автору иногда пересматриваются. Розенталь об этом прямо говорит в последних параграфах, отмечая новые явления в пунктуационном оформлении. Естественно, эти процессы шли и идут и после Розенталя. К тому же у Розенталя именно в части пунктуации есть довольно много неоднозначно трактуемых мест. Наличие справочника Лопатина в основном устраняет эти проблемы. Ценность самого справочника Розенталя при этом не особо страдает.
4. Синтаксис. Это тоже довольно инертная вещь, устаревать тут просто нечему. 
   Для примера возьмем.
   *Валгина Н.С., Розенталь Д.Э., Фомина М.И. Современный русский язык.* 
   Тут вообще Валгина главная. И после смерти Розненталя книга переиздавалась под её редакцией.

Остальное не буду уж разбирать, думаю, достаточно.

Из наиболее востребованных работ упомянул бы еще
*Розенталь Д. Э., Голуб И. Б., Теленкова М. А. Современный русский язык: Учебное пособие.*

Но это все-таки не справочник, а к методической литературе применяются свои критерии актуальности. В целом книга отражает состояние именно на момент её издания - сразу после смерти Д.Э.  Сейчас, конечно, ситуация несколько иная, но ничего хотя бы частично покрывающего весь объем книги не издано.

И маленькое замечание в сторону. Язык вещь живая, у него есть своя история. Даже теряющие актуальность книги не стоит списывать в утиль. Они отражают срез языка на момент их издания. Понимание современных веяний часто просто невозможно вне исторического аспекта.

Comment: Проверьте пункт 4: устревать *просто* или *непросто*?

Comment: @М_Г - спасибо. там слово пропало.

Comment: Спасибо за ценные сведения. Таких противников я не встречала, просто готовлюсь к разборкам с редактором.

Answer (score -1):

Не доверяйте. Верьте. Это разные вещи. 
Доверять - это когда вы полагаетесь на другого человека в том, что он сделает всё так, как вам надо. Верить - это когда вы полагаете, что полученные вами сведения правдивы. Доверяют дела, верят в знание.  
Есть это разъяснение в каких-либо справочниках? Нету. Стало быть верить справочникам нельзя.

Вот и пример вам, пожалуйста: https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/449956/192648